# Correct form of 'no matter'

Tags: grammar

Is it wrong to say that " no matters how..." the point is that can we use  plural form of 'matter' in this phrase?!

Comment: The idiom is _no matter_, not *_no matters._  In any event, it's not clear whether _matter_ in the idiom is a noun (and thus might have a plural -s), or a verb (with a present singular -s).

Comment: I agree with John Lawler's first sentence, but it seems fairly clear to me that *no matter* is a noun phrase, as in the anecdotal philosophy  question "What is mind? No matter. Then what is matter? Never mind."

Answer (score 2):

It is an idiomatic expression, [No matter what/how:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-matter)

> We can use [no matter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/no-matter) to link two clauses as a conjunction. ***It is a short form of it does not matter.***

(Cambridge Dictionary)

> You use no matter in expressions such as '*no matter how*' and '*no matter what*' to say that something is true or happens in all circumstances.

(Collins Dictionary)

> ***[No matter what](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/no--matter)***. Regardless, it makes no difference, as in
>
> - *No matter what I say, she'll do what she likes , or The car must be repaired, no matter what*. [Mid-1500s]

(AHD)

Comment: Yes i knew what you are saying but the question is that Is it wrong to make a change to an idiomatic expression OR structure and word of idioms shouldn't be changed?

Comment: @AmirRazavi You can change an idiom but you wouldn't be as quickly or easily understood. In the case of *no matters how*, people hearing it would think a mistake was made.